# std::shared_ptr of abstract class to instantiate derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, smart-pointers

I am trying to use `std::shared_ptr`, but i am not sure if i can use `shared_ptr` for a abstract class and call a derived class from this smart pointer. Here is the code that i have at present

```
IExecute *ppCIExecuteExecuteOperation = NULL;

for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    switch (stOperationType.key)
    {
        case E_OPERATIONKEY::DrawCircle:
        pCIExecuteExecuteOperation = new CCircle();
        break;
        case E_OPERATIONKEY::DrawSquare:
        pCIExecuteExecuteOperation = new CSquare();
        break;
        case E_OPERATIONKEY::Rhombus:
        pCIExecuteExecuteOperation = new CRehombus();
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
} 
pCIExecuteExecuteOperation->Draw();
```

Here IExecute is a abstract class and CCircle, CSquare, CRhombus is a derived class of IExecute.

All I want to do is use `shared_ptr<IEXectue>pCIExecuteExecuteOperation(nullptr)`
and inside a switch statement make it point to one of the derived class, How can i achieve this?

Edit:
The answers were to use make_shared or reset()

Thanks guys, I dint expect it to be so easy.

Comment: Have you actually tried to do it?

Comment: The obvious way should work.

Comment: @Geoffroy: i am new to c++ shared_ptr, ran through few sites and was confused

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's easy. Look at code and feel.

```
std::shared_ptr<IExecute> ppCIExecuteExecuteOperation;

for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    switch (stOperationType.key)
    {
        case E_OPERATIONKEY::DrawCircle:
            pCIExecuteExecuteOperation.reset(new CCircle());
            break;
        case E_OPERATIONKEY::DrawSquare:
            pCIExecuteExecuteOperation.reset(new CSquare());
            break;
        case E_OPERATIONKEY::Rhombus:
            pCIExecuteExecuteOperation.reset(new CRehombus());
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
} 
pCIExecuteExecuteOperation->Draw();
```

Comment: Isn't it safer in terms of memory leaks to use `std::make_shared` instead of `new`?

Comment: @evotion why? could you explain me?

Comment: The notes at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) show this. Well the question is, if this code is even good practice, because it is hard to read without make_shared, but it can lead to problems.

Comment: @evotion No, that's okay to directly `new` in this case. The point of that cppref page is relate to order of evalution, but in my case that doesn't occur.

Comment: Thank you guys, but i want to know what is the difference in using std::make_shared and "new" as mentioned in the above code

Comment: In this case not because you are using reset instead of constructing a new shared_ptr by calling the std::shared constructor. I never seen that use of `reset()`. Is there any reason preferring `reset()`? In my opinion a call to `make_shared` or the ctor of `shared_ptr` combined with the assignment operator is better to read.

Comment: @user2882262 I prefer the `make_shared` approach because it improves the readability. It also seams to me that it is the most used approach, despite maybe the `shared_ptr<T>(newT())` approach, which can lead to a memory leak as mentioned in an earlier post. I actually read some books and articles about `shared_ptr`, but it is the first time I see the use of `reset` for assigning a `shared_ptr`. If I am honest, I did not new of `reset` before and looked it up.

Comment: Both approaches are referenced on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/operator=/) as a method to acquire ownerwhip of an object, so its probably just a preference thing.

Comment: Thank you @evotion for the detailed description..

Comment: @evotion I use `reset` because it just makes code more shorter and easy.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
IExecute *ppCIExecuteExecuteOperation = NULL;
```

should be replace with

```
std::shared_ptr<IExecute> pExecute;
```

and then each of the lines with assignments can be written as

```
pExecute.reset(new CCircle);
```

Then you can call `Draw`

```
pExecute->Draw();
```

Comment: Thank you,  it was explained in detail and its working now

Comment: I can't vote up, I do not have enough reputation to vote..

Comment: But I the answers helped you, you should accept one of them

Answer (score 2):

The method `std::make_shared<T>` creates a shared pointer object of type `T` and calls its constructor. So instead of calling `new` call `std::make_shared`.

```
std::shared_ptr<IEXectue>pCIExecuteExecuteOperation(nullptr);
...
...
switch (stOperationType.key)
{
    case E_OPERATIONKEY::DrawCircle:
    pCIExecuteExecuteOperation = std::make_shared<CCircle>();
    break;
    ...
```

`std::make_shared` is also able to use paramaters, which are forwarded to the constructor, assuming there is a construcotr with that paramater list.